# Special (escaped) characters in replacements array in preg_replace get escaped

Tags: php, escaping, preg-replace, special-characters

I’m trying to modify a string of the following form where each field is delimited by a tab except for the first which is followed by two or more tabs.

```
"$str1      $str2   $str3   $str4   $str5   $str6"
```

The modified string will have each field wrapped in HTML table tags, and be on its own, indented line as so.

```
"<tr>
  <td class="title">$str1</td>
  <td sorttable_customkey="$str2"></td>
  <td sorttable_customkey="$str3"></td>
  <td sorttable_customkey="$str4"></td>
  <td sorttable_customkey="$str5"></td>
  <td sorttable_customkey="$str6"></td>
</tr>

"
```

I tried using code like the following to do it.

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0]='/^/';
$patterns[1]='/\t\t+/';
$patterns[2]='/\t/';
$patterns[3]='/$/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0]='\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td class="title">';
$replacements[1]='</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="';
$replacements[2]='"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="';
$replacements[3]='"></td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n';

for ($i=0; $i<count($lines); $i++) {
  $lines[$i] = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $lines[$i]);
}
```

The problem is that the escaped characters (tabs and newlines) in the replacement array remain escaped in the destination string and I get the following string.

```
"\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td class="title">$str</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="$str2"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="$str3"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="$str4"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="$str5"></td>\r\n\t\t\t<td sorttable_customkey="$str6"></td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n"
```

Strangely, this line I tried earlier on *does* work:

```
$data=preg_replace("/\t+/", "\t", $data);
```

Am I missing something? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: (Yes, I know that I have to tweak the strings a bit because they overlap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double quotes or heredocs for the replacement string - PCRE only parses those escape characters in the search string.

In your working example `preg_replace("/\t+/", "\t", $data)` those are both literal tab characters because they're in double quotes.

If you changed it to `preg_replace('/\t+/', '\t', $data)` you can observe your main problem - PCRE understands that the `\t` in the search string represents a tab, but doesn't for the one in the replacement string.

So by using double quotes for the replacement, e.g. `preg_replace('/\t+/', "\t", $data)`, you let PHP parse the `\t` and you get the expected result.

It is slightly incongruous, just something to remember.

Comment: Thank you very much. (Actually, I always use double-quotes, and the only reason I used the single-quotes was so that I wouldn’t have to bother escaping the doubles in my strings; go figure.) Hey, you just broke 1,000!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$replacements` array has all its strings decalred as single-quoted strings.
That means that escaped characters won't scape (except `\'`).

It is not related directly to PCRE regular expressions, but to how PHP handles strings.

Basically you can type strings like these:

```
<?php # String test

$value = "substitution";
$str1 = 'this is a $value that does not get substituted';
$str2 = "this is a $value that does not remember the variable"; # this is a substitution that does not remember the variable
$str3 = "you can also type \$value = $value" # you can also type $value = substitution
$bigstr =<<< MARKER
you can type
very long stuff here
provided you end it with the single
value MARKER you had put earlier in the beginning of a line
just like this:
MARKER;
```

tl;dr version: problem is single quotes in the `$replacements` and `$patterns` that should be double quotes